# Magento 2 Mobile Navigation Menu Respond Too Late

Tags: magento2, megamenu, mobile-menu, mobile-device, category-navigation

I have setup Magento 2.4.2 on the server and all functionality working perfectly.
but only the navigation menu takes too much time to respond in mobile view incognito mode only.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the question. Are you saying that pages are loading slowly when navigating on mobile using incognito mode?

Comment: page is fullly folded than also navigation menu is not clickable , it will clickable after some time, this issue is only in incognito mode means first time page loading

Answer (score 0):

If your page is fully rendering, but it takes a long time for the navigation menu to become clickable, then this suggest to me that JavaScript may be taking a long time to load. You would not see this problem in standard mode, of course, because the JS would be cached in the client browser.

To troubleshoot further, I would first make sure JS minification is enabled. This should always be enabled even if that's not the problem in this case: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044482152-Optimize-CSS-and-JS-files-in-Magento-Commerce

Then, if minification is enabled and the menu is still slow to become responsive, I would load the page in Chrome, but simulate mobile mode as explained here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/

This enables you to view the page load waterfall through dev tools and pinpoint what exactly is slowing down the menu's responsiveness. These are the steps I would take to seek to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any plug in? Checked your error log?

Comment: yes there are so many plugins are used but i think it's not related to navigation

Comment: yes there are so many plugins are used but i think it's not related to navigation

Answer (score 0):

From what you have explained its an issue of JS loading pretty late.

For any webpage first the head is downloaded and the js css in head not defined as async or differ are downloaded. After this complete html is downloaded and later all the js and css are downloaded. Or if requireJs is in use then requireJs will download these files.

The feeling is that the JS needed for navigation was downloaded very late.
You need to identify the JS file needed and make sure you define as early as possible in body or you can even plan to define that in head( this can reduce the scores related to web vitals).